# android scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

anyone whether scrollview works only on Linearlayout because i tried absolute layout but there is a problem in scrolling it

thanks in advance

Comment: it works in all.but you have to eleborate whr you get prob and what?

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated. Please do not use it.

Answer (score 1):

try this code  this is helpfull

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutHelp" 
  android:background="@android:color/white">
<------pasted in views--------->
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```